# Assistance Required with LinkedIn API Integration

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I am in the process of integrating the LinkedIn API into my website. The goal is to allow users to log in using their LinkedIn accounts and subsequently retrieve their profile information.

Specifically, I am interested in obtaining comprehensive details about their past work experiences (positions) and educational background.

Currently, I am utilizing the following endpoint:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(geoLocation(geo~,autoGenerated))
```

However, I am facing an issue with the response – when including the "geoLocation" parameter in the projection, the response object is empty. Conversely, if I remove the "geoLocation" parameter, I only receive the first name and last name.

Could you kindly guide me on the correct endpoint to use for retrieving past work experiences, positions, and education background details? Additionally, if there are specific steps or parameters that need to be included for a comprehensive profile response, I would greatly appreciate your assistance.